# Wordpress - Public side and Private side

Tags: permissions

I'm wanting to setup a Wordpress site which has posts for public view and some which are only seen by people that are logged in (authors etc). I dont want the public people to see "Restricted Content" message or anything, just they cant see the posts and if the go to a post direct it'll push them back to the home page.

How can I achvied this so that its easy to select which posts can/can't be viewed by public users?

help please

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Wordpress with members area. You can install third party plugins to do this the easy way. You can check this up : http://www.mytechopinion.com/2009/07/5-ways-add-membership-wordpress.html